# Open an image and re-save it with the same parameters, c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, save

In my code I am opening a bitmap image and simply re-save it. It should maintain the same quality and properties. But as a result the image changes in size, though resolution stays the same and visually there are no changes. How do I open an image and save it, without making any changes?
My code:

```
            Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(path, true);
            img.Save(path);
```

In future it should change only opacity of the image, but right now it just opens and saves it. Why the image size is changing? It becomes smaller in size than it was(386 against 301 Kb)

**UPDATE:**

I did the same with JPG format image, size remained the same. Only PNG is changing its size. On another PNG file size has grown bigger. is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: `Bitmap.Save` saves by default the image in `PNG` i think. Is that the same image format as the image you are loading?

Comment: PNG is losless, so perhaps the filesize might change, the pixels/quality itself remain the same.

Comment: I used the answer below to ensure I am saving as png, but size is still changing. @CasparKleijne I need size to remain the same, is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry if the filesize changes. PNG is a lossless format that compresses files while maintaining all the information. That does mean, that even if the filesize decreases, the information and exact color of each pixel will remain the same.

How big the file gets depends on the algorithm used by the library used to save the image. For different libraries and programs the algorithm can differ a little. Thats why the size of your image changes. You cannot avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably saving the image in a different imageformat to the original file. If, for example,the original image is a `GIF`, you should do something like this:

```
img.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

And like this with any format.

Comment: I am opening a .png file and saving it as a .png, I tried using your way, but size is still changing.

Comment: @SamStone Well,then maybe .Net png algorithm is different to the one used to save your original image, or maybe is changing the color depth, thus causing that file size difference. Just to check, you can try to do this same operation with a .net generated png file, i mean, open and save the file generated in your first step to see if it changes. You can also use any image info software to compare both images to see if there's something different...

Answer (score 0):

The PNG encoder in `System.Drawing` doesn't compress images particularly heavily and there is no way to change it. The `EncoderParameters` property that many have tried to use are simply ignored.

Different PNG encoders in available software offer different compression functionality and the difference you will see is that difference in compression. The first was probable saved with no compression and the second with heavier compression.